# Select <TD> javascript

Tags: php, javascript, sql, sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo uma rotina com uma tabela dinâmica utilizando javascript, onde ao abrir a rotina aparece um botão 'ADICIONAR TABELA'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o usuario clica em 'ADICIONAR TABELA' aparece o cabeçalho da tabela e um botão 'ADD' que é responsável por adicionar linhas a tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é o seguinte: Gostaria de realizar um select no banco de dados 'SQL SERVER' utilizando javascript + php. Onde ao digitar o número do pedido na coluna pedido as outras colunas sejam completadas automaticamente com os dados do pedido digitado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EX01: Digito o número do pedido

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao digitar o número do pedido e dar um 'TAB', o sistema dá um select no banco de dados trazendo os dados das colunas: 'DATA EMISSAO', 'LIBERAÇÃO FINANCEIRO', 'DIAS NA FÁBRICA', 'CLIENTE', 'UF', 'VALOR', 'VOLUME', 'PESO' referente ao pedido digitado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
 $("#multiuso").append(newRow);
   var liveTableData = $('table').tableExport({formats: ["xlsx","xls", "csv", "txt"],    });
   liveTableData.reset();
  //  função para adicionar linhas na tabela especifica, .addRows+n+ = id criado dinamicamente para que ao clicar no botão o sistema inclua a linha na tabela do is especifico
  $(".addRows"+n+"").on('click',function(){
      //alert(n);
      //Variável que recebe a linha que será adicionada na tabela.
    var newRowContent = '<tr>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td>'+n+' ENTREGA</td>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td contenteditable="true" class="numPedido" id = "numPedido" name ="numPedido[1]" ></td>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td class="dtEmissao" id = "dtEmissao" name ="dtEmissao[2]" ></td>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td class="dtLibFin" id = "dtLibFin" name ="dtLibFin[3]" ></td>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td class="diaFabrica" id = "diaFabrica" name ="diaFabrica[4]"></td>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td class="cliente" id = "cliente" name ="cliente[5]"></td>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td class="uf" id = "uf" name ="uf[6]"></td>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td class="valor" id = "valor" name ="valor[7]"></td>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td class="volume" id = "volume" name ="volume[8]"></td>';
        newRowContent +=  '<td class="peso" id = "peso" name ="peso[9]"></td>';
        newRowContent += '<td class="actions">';
        newRowContent += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger removebutton"  type="button">Remover</button> </tr>';
        newRowContent += '</tr>';
       $(newRowContent).appendTo($("#tab"+n+" > tbody"));
       liveTableData.reset();

    });
```

Comment: Tem que pesquisar sobre Ajax, tem muito material aqui no site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, vamos lá:

vamos por partes...

> Ao digitar o número do pedido e dar um 'TAB'

para este ponto você pode usar o evento [onBlur](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp), após criar a sua função.

> o sistema dá um select no banco de dados trazendo os dados das colunas: 'DATA EMISSAO', 'LIBERAÇÃO FINANCEIRO', 'DIAS NA FÁBRICA', 'CLIENTE', 'UF', 'VALOR', 'VOLUME', 'PESO' referente ao pedido digitado.

Para isso você pode fazer uma requisição via ajax (um exemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527586/how-to-replace-html-element-with-ajax-response) ), para que possa recuperar os valores do banco de dados.

Vou dar um exemplo:

Você pode criar isso referenciando o objeto DOM diretamente na chamada da função:

função js:

```
function recupera_valores(val){
    console.log(val);
    //aqui você coloca seu código da requisição ajax
}
```

Desta forma é possível você preencher os dados na linha pegando o elemento  parent do seu elemento referenciado.

para fazer a chamada, na hora de criar a sua row basta você adicionar a função onblur no seu input, exemplo:

```
$(".addRows"+n+"").on('click',function(){
  //alert(n);
  //Variável que recebe a linha que será adicionada na tabela.
var newRowContent = '<tr>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td>'+n+' ENTREGA</td>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td contenteditable="true" class="numPedido" id = "numPedido" name ="numPedido[1]" onBlur="recupera_valores(this);"></td>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td class="dtEmissao" id = "dtEmissao" name ="dtEmissao[2]" ></td>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td class="dtLibFin" id = "dtLibFin" name ="dtLibFin[3]" ></td>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td class="diaFabrica" id = "diaFabrica" name ="diaFabrica[4]"></td>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td class="cliente" id = "cliente" name ="cliente[5]"></td>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td class="uf" id = "uf" name ="uf[6]"></td>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td class="valor" id = "valor" name ="valor[7]"></td>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td class="volume" id = "volume" name ="volume[8]"></td>';
    newRowContent +=  '<td class="peso" id = "peso" name ="peso[9]"></td>';
    newRowContent += '<td class="actions">';
    newRowContent += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger removebutton"  type="button">Remover</button> </tr>';
    newRowContent += '</tr>';
   $(newRowContent).appendTo($("#tab"+n+" > tbody"));
   liveTableData.reset();

});
```

ou você pode criar uma função para a classe numpedido:

```
$('.numpedido').blur(function(){
     console.log(this);
    //aqui vai seu código
});
```

o processo é o mesmo, porém com essa forma você não precisa modificar nada em seu código.

Você também pode criar um ID na hora de montar a tabela e chamar uma função referenciando o id da row... enfim, existem inúmeras formas de fazer o que você precisa.

Poderia postar o código inteiro, mas ai sairia do propósito da comunidade.

Espero ter ajudado e qualquer dúvida estou à disposição.

Comment: Obrigado Alvaro pela ajuda irei dar continuidade no projeto.